# Query function not working when I add WHERE in formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

When I use the query function in Google sheets it works fine until I try to add `WHERE` condition. I want to only pull data that contains a `TRUE` value in Column 10.  Right now my query function can pull all of the data but when I try to add the `WHERE` condition the query does not pull any data even though there are `TRUE` values in Column 10.

I have tried using the `WHERE` condition to pull values from different columns and it has been unsuccessful. Anytime I try to add the `WHERE` condition in my query formula no data is pulled.

Below code works to pull all data:

```
=QUERY({RepTemplate1!A4:AC63;RepTemplate2!A5:AC64},"SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9, Col10, Col11",1)
```

Below code does NOT work to pull specified data:

```
=QUERY({RepTemplate1!A4:AC63;RepTemplate2!A5:AC64},"SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9, Col10, Col11 WHERE Col10 = 'TRUE'",1)
```

There is no error message for the formula that is not working. The headers appear just no data.

Not sure where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or try `FILTER`:

```
={RepTemplate1!A4:K4; 
  FILTER({RepTemplate1!A5:K63; RepTemplate2!A5:K64},
         {RepTemplate1!J5:J63; RepTemplate2!J5:J64}=TRUE)}
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Google sheets doesn't seem to recognize the FILTER condition. (Could be user error, I am fairly new to queries in Google sheets)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F9tpxTkCn1OWLtzWnKwbYzs5VwsU6KJcCfNIVwSZZMI/edit#gid=1388423370

Comment: I did some troubleshooting and got the CONTAINS condition to pull values but I am having trouble getting the formula to pull values from column 10. I want the TRUE values (checked boxes) in column 10 (J) on the RepTemplate1 and RepTemplate2 tabs to be the only values that appear on the Manager Data Test Tab.

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: Sorry about that

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F9tpxTkCn1OWLtzWnKwbYzs5VwsU6KJcCfNIVwSZZMI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The Manager Test and Manager Data Test tabs contain the formulas I THINK should be correct...

Comment: I want the data with positive values from columns J & K on the RepTemplate sheets to populate on the Manager Data Test tab. Then, I want the data with positive Values from column L on the Manager Data Test tab to populate on the Manager Test tab.

Comment: Awesome!. Thank you. Was I just not supposed to use the apostrophes when adding TRUE?

Comment: @AustinFarmer yes, exactly

Answer (score 1):

Google Sheets reads `TRUE` as boolean and not string. So you may want to try the same query without the single quotation marks:

```
=QUERY({RepTemplate1!A4:AC63;RepTemplate2!A5:AC64},"SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9, Col10, Col11 WHERE Col10 = TRUE",1)
```